# R: How to find out dimension (width, height) of OpenStreetMap data before defining png device?

Tags: r, png, openstreetmap, dimension

How can I use OpenStreetMap to get map data and write it to a png file in the best possible quality? In other words: How do I know width and height of the OSM data before defining the png device?

The following example gets OSM data from Washington DC. I'm guessing the size two times clearly wrong:

1. 2000 x 2000 px
2. 200 x 400 px

```r
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
library(OpenStreetMap)
# Washington DC
upperLeft  <- c(40.00,-78.00)
lowerRight <- c(38.00,-76.00)
# get OpenStreetMap map
map <- openmap(upperLeft, lowerRight, minNumTiles=4)

# How to find out the correct size other than try&error???

pngWidth  <- 2000 # => white border left and right
pngHeight <- 2000 # => picture not sharp
# open PNG device
png("washingtondc_2000x2000.png", width=pngWidth, height=pngHeight)
# avoid useless border
par(mai=c(0,0,0,0)) # margin area in inches
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0)) # margin area in number of lines (rows) of text
par(xaxs="i", yaxs="i") # x- and y-axis won't be extended
# plot on PNG device
plot(map)
# close PNG device
dev.off()

pngWidth  <- 200 # => white border top and bottom
pngHeight <- 400 # => text unreadable small
# open PNG device
png("washingtondc_0200x0400.png", width=pngWidth, height=pngHeight)
# avoid useless border
par(mai=c(0,0,0,0)) # margin area in inches
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0)) # margin area in number of lines (rows) of text
par(xaxs="i", yaxs="i") # x- and y-axis won't be extended
# plot on PNG device
plot(map)
# close PNG device
dev.off()
```

The first try (2000 x 2000) results in white borders to the left and right. Also it looks not sharp because the OSM map pixels are stretched to the too high 2000 px.

[image: 2000x2000]
<sub>(source: [ibin.co](https://ibin.co/2S6WbxAc24a9))</sub>

The second try (200 x 400) results in borders at top and bottom and unreadable text due to the much too small resolution.

[image: 200x400]
<sub>(source: [ibin.co](https://ibin.co/2S6X0vluDAEU))</sub>

---

Addition 1:

If I cut away all white border from the 2000x2000 png file the leftover is 1555x1998. The aspect ratio therefore is `1555 / 1998 = 0,778278278`.

Now I take closer look at `map <- openmap(upperLeft, lowerRight, minNumTiles=4)`:

```r
> summary(map)
      Length Class  Mode
tiles 1      -none- list
bbox  2      -none- list

> summary(map$tiles)
     Length Class   Mode
[1,] 5      osmtile list

>  map$tiles
[[1]]
$colorData
    [1] "#F1EEE8" "#F1EEE8" "#F1EEE8" "#F1EEE8" "#F1EEE8" "#F1EEE8" "#F4D5A7"
 <snip>
 [99996] "#DCDCDC" "#E6D5B7" "#F6C378" "#E98587"
 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 69159 entries ]

$bbox
 <snip>

$projection
 <snip>

$xres
[1] 466

$yres
[1] 363

attr(,"class")
[1] "osmtile"
```

Here the `$xres` and `$yres` look interesting. I do not know what these data mean but I would have expected `$xres` to be smaller than `$yres`. Anyway, I divided again: `$yres / $xres = 363 / 466 = 0,778969957`. This is almost the aspect ratio from the cropped image.

Does that mean anything? How could I access `$xres` directly? I would have thought s.th. like `map$tiles$xres` but that is `NULL`.

I'm still in the dark. And the aspect ratio alone is not enough. I'd like to have also the total width and height for best quality.

---

Addition 2:

@[glenn-randers-pehrson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2031419/glenn-randers-pehrson):

The great circle distance does not work here because the image is a deformed representation (=rectangle) of a piece of a sphere surface. (Please excuse my bad English.)

Great circle distances come quite close but not exactly to the image's aspect ratio. If I cut away all white border from the 2000x2000 png file the leftover is a rectangle with 1555x1998 px. The aspect ratio therefore is `1555 / 1998 = 0,778278278`.

The NW->NE to NW->SW ratio calculated with great circles is `0.7691904`:

```r
library(geosphere)
upperLeft  <- c(40.00,-78.00) # lat lon
lowerRight <- c(38.00,-76.00) # lat lon
NW <- c(upperLeft[2],  upperLeft[1])  # lon lat
SW <- c(upperLeft[2],  lowerRight[1]) # lon lat
NE <- c(lowerRight[2], upperLeft[1])  # lon lat
SE <- c(lowerRight[2], lowerRight[1]) # lon lat

dist_NW_NE <- distGeo(NW, NE)
dist_NW_SW <- distGeo(NW, SW)
dist_NW_NE / dist_NW_SW

[1] 0.7691904
```

The SW->SE to NE->SE ratio of course is bigger because distances between longitudes are bigger if you are nearer to the equator. It is `0.7911577`:

```r
dist_SW_SE <- distGeo(SW, SE)
dist_NE_SE <- distGeo(NE, SE)
dist_SW_SE / dist_NE_SE

[1] 0.7911577
```

However, I could take the average of both values as a approximation. But then I still lack the total width and height for best quality.

---

Addition 3:

Same calculation as above but not with the edges but with the centerlines. The ratio still is different to the png's ratio: `0.7802934`

```r
N <- c(-77, 40)
S <- c(-77, 38)
W <- c(-78, 39)
E <- c(-76, 39)
dist_W_E <- distGeo(W, E)
dist_N_S <- distGeo(N, S)
dist_W_E / dist_N_S

[1] 0.7802934
```

I think the solution should be less at geo calculations but more somewhere in analysing the image data tranfered from OSM.

Comment: You can calculate the aspect ratio from your upper left and lower right corners.

Comment: So the width-height-ratio should be `(78-76)/(40-38) = 2/2 = 1`. The 2000x2000 example shows that this is not the case.

Comment: # Washington DC
upperLeft  <- c(40.00,-78.00)
lowerRight <- c(38.00,-76.00) These coordinates are in degrees lattitude and longitude, not pixels or miles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally found the solution.

I get some graphical data from OpenStreetMap:

```r
library(OpenStreetMap)
upperLeft  <- c(40.00,-78.00)
lowerRight <- c(38.00,-76.00)
map <- openmap(upperLeft, lowerRight, minNumTiles=4)
```

Now the question is what width and length does this image have? Answer:

```r
pngWidth  <- map$tiles[[1]]$yres[1]
pngHeight <- map$tiles[[1]]$xres[1]
```

That is 363 x 466 px. So the png is:

```r
fileName <- paste(c("washingtondc_", width, "x", height, ".png"), collapse='')
png(fileName, width=pngWidth, height=pngHeight)
plot(map)
dev.off()
```

[image: 363x466]
<sub>(source: [ibin.co](https://ibin.co/2SB7AGgNCUvs))</sub>

---

Bonus information: `raster()` gives a nice overview:

```r
library(OpenStreetMap)
library(raster)
raster <- raster(map)
raster

class       : RasterStack 
dimensions  : 466, 363, 169158, 3  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 613.3305, 614.8422  (x, y)
extent      : -8682920, -8460281, 4579426, 4865942  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs 
names       : layer.1, layer.2, layer.3 
min values  :      52,      51,      51 
max values  :     253,     253,     253
```

The `$xres` from `map$tiles` confused me because it shows the height value. But `raster()` names the same value `nrow` which makes more sense at least for me. Same for `map$tiles[[1]]$yres[1]` vs. `raster()`'s `ncol`.

Answer (score 1):

```
# Washington DC 
upperLeft <- c(40.00,-78.00)
lowerRight <- c(38.00,-76.00)
```

These coordinates are in degrees latitude and longitude, not pixels or miles.

You can use the free online [GPS Visualizer service](http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/calculators) or similar software to calculate the great circle distance between two points.

- Enter 39,-76 and 39,-78 to get the distanceEastWest
- Enter 38,-77 and 40,-77 to get the distanceNorthSouth
- Divide distanceNorthSouth by distanceEastWest to get the height/width aspect ratio.
- It does not matter what units you choose for distance.  Most systems will offer you to choose miles, nautical miles, or kilometers.

Comment: I will put a longer answer in my inital question because space is limited in the comments.

Great circle distances come quite close but not exactly to the image's aspect ratio. The aspect ratio of the png file without borders is `0,778278278`.

The NW->NE to NW->SW ratio calculated with great circles is `0.7691904`.

The SW->SE to NE->SE ratio is bigger because distances between longitudes are bigger if you are nearer to the equator. It is `0.7911577`.

However, I could take the average of both values as a approximation. But then I still lack the total width and height for best quality.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry: I didn't see that you did not mean the edges of the rectangle but centerlines. I add that case to the question above (Addition 3). The ratio here again differs from the png's aspect ratio: png = `0,778278278` vs. geo centerlines = `0.7802934`.